# Colorbox - removing the close button from a specific window

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using the colorbox plugin to display messages on my web page.
One of them is a "wait for response" message, and I don't want the user closing it by himself.

I know how to unbind the ESC key, and to disable the overlay close, but I still have a problem with the close button.
I found I could remove it in the css like this: #cboxClose{display:none !important;} 
but this will effect all my colorbox messages..

Is there a way to remove the close button from a specific message? Maybe from the jsp itself?

Thanks,
Yael.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What about removing the button after this specific box has opened via jquery. Colorbox provides you with the necessary event hook:

```
$('selector').colorbox({onLoad: function() {
    $('#cboxClose').remove();
}});
```

Comment: could you give an example for "removeButtonDelegate". I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: I modified the example to include the actual delegate. Instead of removing it you could also hide it I guess.

Comment: Better to user .hide() as if you're transitioning to another colorbox you can then show the button again if needed.

Comment: Even better: onOpen -> `$("#colorbox").addClass("noClose");`, onClosed -> `$("#colorbox").removeClass("noClose");`, and in css: `.noClose #cboxClose{display:none}`

Answer (score 8):

Thanks ntziolis this is exactly what I was looking for.  I was able to add this to my colorbox call like so.  I am using it to open a separate web page, notice the iframe:true

```
$(".class_name").colorbox({innerWidth:500, innerHeight:400, iframe:true, escKey:false, overlayClose:false,onLoad: function() {
    $('#cboxClose').remove();
}});
```

Answer (score 7):

there is a option in newer version of colorbox

closeButton true    Set to false to remove the close button.

see here
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

closeButton: false

Comment: This is a much better solution. When you do .remove, it removes the functionality from any colorbox on that page (but leaves the close button).

Comment: It's not my question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#myColorbox").colorbox({
    escKey: false, //escape key will not close
    overlayClose: false, //clicking background will not close
    closeButton: false // hide the close button
});
```

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please read "[answer]" then [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: I'm voting to delete this, because it appears to be the same as existing answers. Don't add **thank you**, or **confirmation** answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) from quality contributions, you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34523260)